# Custom post type draft use wrong template

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, draft

I have a custom post type called `agenda` with a custom post template called `single-agenda.php`.

When I have a draft of an `agenda` post, this uses the content in the template `single.php`. When I publish it's ok, it uses the content in `single-agenda.php`.

I would like to see my draft content in `single-agenda.php`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

> In some cases, the permalink structure must be updated in order for
>   the new template files to be accessed when viewing posts of a custom
>   post type. To do this, go to Administration Panels > Settings >
>   Permalinks, change the permalink structure to a different structure,
>   save the changes, and change it back to the desired structure.

from http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Type_Templates

Comment: I've already tried, but nothing has changed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a bug in WP?

Well not testet, but it should be something like this.

```
function wpse_115432_template_redirect() {
    global $post;

    if ( 'agenda' != $post->post_type && 'draft' != $post->post_status )
        return;

    $template_path = TEMPLATEPATH . '/' . "single-agenda.php";

    if ( !file_exists( $template_path ) )
        return;

    include($template_path);
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse_115432_template_redirect');
```

Comment: Hello Horttcore,
Thanks for your answer. I've pasted this function in my function.php but nothing change, with old and new draft created.

Comment: Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I've tried it with 'page' post type so it should defiantly work.